# sql case statement based on number of occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I have a table (t1) with email addresses, users and domain names:

```
     email                user         domain
joe123@domain.com        joe123        domain.com
sue234@email.net         sue234        email.net
      ...                  ...          ...
```

And another table (t2) of whether an email sent to an address was opened:

```
  Opened             Email
    0            joe123@domain.com
    1            sue234@email.net
    0            jack55@mybarber.com
   ...               ...
```

I'd like to join t1.domain to t2 but only domains that occur more than 100x.

I can create a table with occurrence count

```
SELECT domain, count(domain) cntDomain
from table1
group by domain
```

with a result like this:

```
   domain         cntDomain
 domain.com       5000
 email.net        4300
 mybarber.com     67
```

the resulting table would look like this:

```
  Opened             Email                 domain
    0            joe123@domain.com         domain.com
    1            sue234@email.net          email.net
    0            jack55@mybarber.com       other 
   ...               ...
```

but can't figure out the join (I assume it will be a left join to create the 'other' value for infrequently occurring values) and case statement needed to join the value if it occurs more than 100x and if not a value of 'other'.

Comment: You need a `having count(*) > 100`

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table2 t2
inner join
(
    SELECT domain, count(1) cntDomain
    from table1
    group by domain
    having count(1) > 100
) t1 on t2.email = t1.email
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if all the emails in the first table are in the second.  If they are, you can do:

```
select t1.*, t2.domain
from (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by domain) as cnt
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t1.email = t2.email
where cnt > 100;
```

If not, we can check for the domain in the email address itself:

```
select t2.*, t1.domain
from table2 t2 left join
     (select t1.domain, count(*) as cnt
      from table1 t1
      group by t1.domain
     ) t1
     on t2.email like '%@' + t1.domain and
        cnt > 100;
```

Expect performance on this version to be really, really bad.

Comment: You might want to make the second query's first join condition `t2.email like '%@' + t1.domain` to keep sub-domains separated.

Comment: @Allan . . . That makes a lot of sense.  Thank you.  It also affects things like `gmail.com` versus `mail.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses an inner query to obtain counts, and then a case statement to interpret the counts as either the domain or the string `'Other'` as appropriate. Tested it on some play data to ensure it worked, but I haven't an opinion on its performance.

It feels a little awkward, because t1 gets queried twice; once to get the domain, and again to get the counts. Regardless, it gets the job done.

You can swap the number 100 out for another number (or a variable) if the specific threshold changes.

```
select 
  t2.Opened
, t2.Email
, case when t3.cntDomain > 100 then t3.domain else 'Other' end as domain
from t2
left outer join t1 on t2.Email = t1.email
left outer join (
    select t1.domain, count(1) cntDomain
    from t1
    left outer join t2 on t1.email = t2.email
    group by t1.domain
) as t3 on t1.domain = t3.domain
```

**Edit**

If you don't like case statements, this approach might smell more elegant. The inner query is modified with a `having` statement. Now, because of the left join, `t3.domain` will be null in the event that the count is less than the threshold. Add a little `ISNULL` to the select statement for null coalescing, and you're money.

```
select 
  t2.Opened
, t2.Email
, ISNULL(t3.domain, 'Other')
from t2
left outer join t1 on t2.Email = t1.email
left outer join (
    select t1.domain, count(1) cntDomain
    from t1
    left outer join t2 on t1.email = t2.email
    group by t1.domain
    having count(1) > 100
) as t3 on t1.domain = t3.domain
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think Below Query should solve your Problem

```
       SELECT t2.opened,
       t2.Email,
       CASE WHEN tempt1.email is NULL THEN 'Other' ELSE tempt1.domain END as domain
       FROM t2 LEFT JOIN (SELECT email,domain
       FROM t1
       group by domain HAVING  count(domain)>100) tempt1 on t2.Email=tempt1.email
```